# How to customize change password page in ADFS 3.0 and find a list of available query strings?

Tags: adfs

Do you know how can I customize change password page? I want to change displayed warnings and add some information available only on this page. 
I know that MS provides description of the customization sign-in page but I can't find any information about change password page. I think that it can be possible using java script but I haven't tested it.
Do you know how to redirect user to some specific page after successful changing password action? Do you know a list of supported query strings for this page?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe this can help you, this is how to redirect the cancel button back to the original page but can be modified: http://www.gi-architects.co.uk/2016/10/adfs-3-0-cancel-button-redirection-and-password-change-link/

Comment: When posting a link it is helpful if you include some of the main points directly in your answer in case the link is ever broken.

Answer (score 1):

You probably already saw the [official one](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn280950.aspx)?
The password would be [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/samueld/archive/2015/05/13/adfs-2012-r2-now-supports-password-change-not-reset-across-all-devices.aspx), perhaps?